# bash alias-like command recognition based on regexp

Tags: bash

how could I make it possible in bash to parse commands through regex and then replace that with a pre-set correct one?

let's say, I always forget to type "git clone" before pasting a repo url into the terminal.

Now bash shall parse any command typed in containing the strings "git" and "@" and ending with ".git", and replace the whole line with an added "git clone" before.

That would make like easier for a thousand commands. any idea?

Comment: I would just type `git clone !!` after I discovered my error

Comment: You could try to use the `command_not_found_handle` feature of newer versions of bash for this I suppose. But it seems easier to just, when you forget to do this and it fails, do `git clone !!` or `git clone <alt-.>` to run it again using the last command (`!!`) or the last argument of the last command `<alt-.>`.

Comment: the last argument of the last command is also available via history substitution as `!$`.

Comment: If I type in `https://some/path/to/something.git`, how is a mere regex supposed to know if I meant to use `git clone`, or `curl`, or `wget`, or `links`, or something else? You'd be better off just learning to type what you mean...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a function named `command_not_found_handle` which processes, well, commands that haven't been found.

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  local cmd_str

  # change the argument-list array back to a string
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"

  # process that string:
  case $cmd_str in
    "git@"*".git") eval "git clone $cmd_str" ;;
    *) echo "No alternative for command found" >&2; return 1 ;;
  esac
}
```

Using a `case` statement evaluates [glob-style patterns](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) rather than regexes; you can allow [more flexible syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) by enabling the `extglob` [option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options), or use a bunch of `if [[ $str =~ $pattern ]]` tests instead of `case` if you really, *really* do want regular expressions.

Comment: Note that this requires bash 4.x; `/bin/bash` on Macs is still 3.2 as of El Capitan (and for the forseeable future due to a disagreement between Apple and the license in Bash 4).

Comment: Indeed; using MacPorts or similar to install bash 4 is well-advised.

Comment: `cmd_str` isn't necessary, is it? `"git@"*".git") git clone "$@" ;;`.

Comment: @chepner, well, we need to form a string to be able to do pattern or regex matches against it (and the OP did very explicitly ask about regexes). If we're going to be doing that... well, it becomes fairly academic whether we use the original array or the shell-quoted string for the actual execution as well.

Comment: Oh, right. You could, though, just use `case $* in`, since the word is not subject to word-splitting or pathname generation.

Comment: True enough. As long as none of the patterns being matched care about the distinction between syntactic and literal whitespace, I think that would be an entirely reasonable solution as well. Since we don't know the patterns (being given only one example, but with the OP wanting to build a highly general tool), I'm leaning towards precision.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answers! I'll test this function in my bashrc! Of course, the git clone call is just an example. I'm working 99% on terminal, therefore and I'm a fast-typer making typos all the time and also want to make unneccesary (because obvious) words obsolete/automatic. I have evolved a fine set of typing mistake patterns :D now why not catch them! btw I'm only using linux kernels >4.x so bash is always >4.0

Comment: I'm making someting trivial wrong. pasted the function as it is in my .bashrc. logout/login, doesn't get called. How does this function get actually called ?

Comment: @roothahn, the kernel version and the bash version don't actually have anything to do with each other. What does `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` say? What does `type command_not_found_handle` say?

Comment: @roothahn, ...to be clear, I tested this myself by copying-and-pasting directly into my shell window. If your Linux distro already provides a `command_not_found_handle`, and that one is added after the point in shell startup where the relevant part of your `.bashrc` is executed, it could possibly be overriding it. If that's the case, though, the output of the `type` command given above will make it clear.

Comment: ok, the function actually runs, but because there are colon and slash in the git-repo url it thinks I'm calling a path so "no such file or directory". But if I type: "git@bla.git" it returns "No alternative for command found". Thats no problem as I can use this function to trigger other stuff with it :-) thanks a lot again!   btw, I did use the term regular expression just to say I want to check the cmd for an expression. was just the best word I found to describe what I wanted